# Invertir bytes en Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, struct

Espero puedan apoyarme para resolver mi enredo. Actualmente estoy trabajando con valores hexadecimales, y estoy usando una librería que un amigo usa para sus trabajos, el mismo la hizo. Probablemente no entiendan gran parte del código por lo mismo, pero lo importante de mi duda lo marcaré llamativo.

Ahora sí, básicamente lo que quiero hacer es invertir el orden de los bytes en los valores hexadecimales que tengo. Este es mi código:

```
pheader = 0x01E4 #Header(opcode) nada relevante.
item1 = Inventory.GetItem(1,1) #Consulta de un artículo, tampoco es relevante
itemid1 = hex(item1.id)[2:] #Aquí saco el código hex y elimino el '0x' del inicio que no me sirve
itemsn1 = hex(item1.sn)[2:] #Aquí saco el código hex y elimino el '0x' del inicio que no me sirve
print("Item ID: ",itemid1) #Esto nomás lo hago para confirmación
print("Item SN: ",itemsn1) #Esto nomás lo hago para confirmación

#Aquí inicio la estructura del paquete, a partir de aquí casi todo lo que uds quizás no reconozcan es parte de la librería de mi amigo:*

oPacket = Packet.COutPacket(pheader) 
oPacket.EncodeBuffer(" [010000000000000001000000688E7C05{}00{}0100000001000000]".format(itemid1,itemsn1)) #Aquí es donde los paquetes salen con los bytes en un orden que no necesito
Packet.SendPacket(oPacket)
```

**Importante**: La medida de bytes de itemid1 siempre es 3 (6 dígitos), y la de itemsn1 es 8(16 dígitos).

En lo marcado con negrita, podrán observar ustedes que hay 2 llaves donde introduzco los paquetes provenientes de las variables *itemid1* e *itemsn1*, sin embargo al pegarlas ahí, vienen con este orden por ejemplo: **105c28**(itemid1) y **2000050b0000616e**(itemsn1), entonces yo quisiera que esas variables me arrojaran los bytes al revés: **285c10** y **6e6100000b050020** respectivamente. Hay alguna forma de hacerlo? Gracias por responder!

---

Ahora, quisiera saber si por medio de un for loop puedo hacer lo mismo pero con varias cosas de forma simultánea, por ejemplo:

```
extractHeader = 0x01E4
item1 = Inventory.GetItems(1) #En el script pasado, era 1,1 por type,slot, ahora solo quiero que items saque todos los datos que se encuenten en type 1.


oPacket = Packet.COutPacket(pheader)
oPacket.Encode4(len(item1))
for i in range(len(item1)):
oPacket.EncodeBuffer("[010000000000000001000000688E7C05{}{}0100000001000000]".format(little_endian_hex(item1.id),little_endian_hex(item1.sn, "Q")))
Packet.SendPacket(oPacket)
```

Al usar este script de arriba, la consola me da el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError: 'std::vector<SLOTITEM>' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Pues no detecta que item tenga el atributo 'id', ni 'sn', pero si lo hago como tu solucion ( de forma individual ) si lo detecta y hace uso de el.
No se si me haya dado a entender. Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que en realidad el problema que tratas de resolver es codificar en hexadecimal un dato de tipo `long` (32 bits) y otro de tipo `long long` (64 bits) pero en formato *little endian* (la parte baja primero, la parte alta después).

Para este tipo de conversiones de datos a bytes, especificando su *endianness*, Python tiene el módulo `struct`. Este módulo proporciona la función `struct.pack()` a la que como primer parámetro le pasas una cadena que especifica el tamaño y endianity del resultado, y como segundo parámetro el dato (numérico).

Así, por ejemplo, para convertir un entero `long` a sus 4 bytes en orden *little endian* harías:  `struct.pack("<L", dato)`, y si se trata de un `long long` harías `struct.pack("<Q", dato)`. La cadena `"<L"` indica que es un long, y el `<` inicial especifica la endianness deseada.

El resultado de esto es un array de bytes. Puedes recorrer ya ese array elemento a elemento convirtiendo cada uno en hexadecimal y concatenando todos. La siguiente función, por ejemplo, usa este método (junto con un generador para dejarlo todo en una sola línea):

```
import struct

def little_endian_hex(data, size="L"):
  fmt = "<{}".format(size)
  bytes = struct.pack(fmt, data)
  return "".join("{:02x}".format(byte) for byte in bytes)
```

La función recibe como parámetros el dato en sí, y su tamaño (por defecto long). Usa `struct.pack()` para convertirlo en secuencia de bytes, y usa `"".join()` para concatenar los bytes (pasados a hexadecimal mediante el formato `{:02x}` que asegura que siempre tengan dos cifras, rellenando con ceros por la izquierda cada byte si es necesario).

Ejemplo:

```
>>> little_endian_hex(0x105c28)
'285c1000'
>>> little_endian_hex(0x2000050b0000616e, "Q")
'6e6100000b050020'
```

Decías que en tu caso el primer dato tenía siempre 3 bytes, pero he visto que en la cadena final que construyes le añades un 00 al final, por lo que cabe decir que en realidad tiene siempre 4 bytes pero el más alto vale siempre 0. Fíjate que mi método te devuelve también ese cuarto byte (el resultado termina en 00) por lo que no necesitas añadirlo en la cadena final.

Fíjate también que no necesitamos el paso intermedio a hexadecimal, directamente trabajas con los enteros que tienes en tu `item1`. Es decir:

```
oPacket = Packet.COutPacket(pheader)

item1 = Inventory.GetItem(1,1)
oPacket.EncodeBuffer(
   "[010000000000000001000000688E7C05{}{}0100000001000000]".format(
       little_endian_hex(item1.id),
       little_endian_hex(item1.sn, "Q")
     )
   )
```

## Ampliacion

Para repetir la codificación en bucle, suponiendo que `Inventory.GetItems(1)` te devuelva un iterable (veo en tu pregunta que aparentemente devuelve un `std::Vector`, lo cual posiblemente sea iterable), lo siguiente podría funcionar:

```
extractHeader = 0x01E4
items = Inventory.GetItems(1)

oPacket = Packet.COutPacket(pheader)
oPacket.Encode4(len(items))
for item in items:
    oPacket.EncodeBuffer(
         "[010000000000000001000000688E7C05{}{}0100000001000000]".format(
             little_endian_hex(item.id),
             little_endian_hex(item.sn, "Q")))
    Packet.SendPacket(oPacket)
```

Aunque realmente desconozco qué hacen muchas de las funciones que utilizas y no estoy del todo seguro. Confirma si funciona.

Comment: Que buena clase me acabas de dar! Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Y por ejemplo, ahora que ya se hacer esto, quisiera saber is es posible hacer un for loop, donde en vez de consultar un item específico en la consulta "Inventory.GetItem(1,1)", pudiera hacerme lo mismo en todo en general. Modifiqué el post original para no hacer este tan amplio, agradecería infinitamente si me puedes ayudar con eso ultimo :D

Comment: @AlanCarlosLopez He ampliado la respuesta. Mira si te sirve. Es un bucle bastante típico.

Comment: Que tal @abulafia , sigue dandome un error similar, por ejemplo lo que se me ha ocurrido hacer es un bucle incremental usando la variable anterior "item1 = Inventory.GetItem(1,1)", donde el segundo 1 incremente hasta llegar al 28 (numero máximo de items dentro de la funcion Inventory.GetItems(1). Así el buclé haria el incremento hasta llegar a (1,28) sin necesidad de hacer un for loop en items (pues por alguna razon no funciona, me sigue diciento el mismo error de atributo. Cómo podría hacer lo que te menciono?

Comment: No entiendo por qué te da el error de atributo el código que puse. ¿Te has fijado que lo que se le pasa a `little_endian_hex()` es `item.id` y no `item1.id` como antes? De cualquier forma, el enfoque que propones también debería funcionar. Sería un simple: `for n in range(1,29):  item = Inventory.GetItem(1,n)`, etc...